# Power-Off or Restart an android device via Code/Program?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-manifest

Is there any way to restart/shutdown a phone directly from an application?

For Example:
I need to restart/shutdown my Phone when i meet some specific condition...

**Citations to Developer Website:**

Permission to Reboot?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT

Permission to Brick the device???

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BRICK

Method to reboot???

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot%28java.lang.String%29

Method to reboot and Wipe??

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RecoverySystem.html#rebootWipeUserData%28android.content.Context%29

Reboot Method in MonkeyRunner/MonkeyDevice:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/MonkeyDevice.html#reboot

There are options to brick a device but why not to power-down or restart?

I tried the following code but it throws an exception..

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.schogini.PowerOff"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".PowerOffActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Java Code:**

```
package com.schogini.PowerOff;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class PowerOffActivity extends Activity {

    PowerManager pm;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        Button mBuyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mBuyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                pm.reboot("null");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Exception thrown in LogCat:**

```
06-10 17:58:29.001: WARN/dalvikvm(2064): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b160)
06-10 17:58:29.001: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.PowerManager.reboot
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.schogini.PowerOff.PowerOffActivity$1.onClick(PowerOffActivity.java:28)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6545)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-10 17:58:29.011: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2064):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Under what condition would an application need to restart or shutdown the entire phone?

Comment: For a Theft-security app, power off the device in an abnormal scenario.

Comment: Surely the best approach would be to lock the device as I suspect the thief might find the power button and circumvent your app.

Comment: locking a device would be ideal. But i am just asking if its possible then how? There are options to brick a device but why not to power-down or restart?

Comment: Probably because there's no benefit to it.

Comment: But can you explain why these are in the Permissions if they don't exist? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT

Comment: Brick the device???    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BRICK

Comment: Method to reboot??? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: reboot and Wipe?? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RecoverySystem.html#rebootWipeUserData%28android.content.Context%29

Comment: Remote wipe/brick the device may be reasonable approaches to rendering a stolen device useless to the thief. The OS itself is almost certainly going to require the ability to reboot the device following updates. There's nothing surprising here.

Comment: Yup.. Then there is a possibility that it can be done.. In someway...

Comment: There's no doubt it can be done, as @Femi says below, you probably won't have permission from your application so in effect, you can't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a standard Android distribution, no. Suitably rooted phones often have access to `su`/`reboot` commands, but for an off-the-shelf, commercially available device, no: there is no way to do it.

Comment: is there any way to execute the shell command inside our program, in android? What about native applications, are they capable of doing this?

Comment: You can use `Runtime.exec` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[]%29) to fire a shell command but it is doubtful that your application will have the permission required to invoke the REBOOT command. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot%28java.lang.String%29: that might work for you

Comment: @Femi is it possible to disable or prevent the shut down/silent  programmatically? when certain action happens nad device is locked/unlocked ??

Answer (score 6):

you need to sign the application with signapk. jar using the following command:

java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 .apk .apk

for this you need to download and build android source code and flash it on a device. You can find the signapk.jar in the \out\host\linux-x86\framework directory.

for more details please refer to the following link:
http://groups.google.com/group/Android-DevPhone-Updating/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-04?_done=/group/Android-DevPhone-Updating/browse_frm/month/2010-04?&&pli=1

Comment: How signing apk will help to reboot a device?

Comment: I found the answer. Signing is needed for REBOOT permission to work. Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4966542/1455694