# How to disable system dialog window or pop ups in android?

Tags: java, android

I am finding out a way to switch off my tablet automatically.

Right now when we long press power button, I get a confirmation for shutdown (Cancel or Ok). 
Is there a way to programmatically switch off the device without confirmation ?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Suitably rooted phones/tablets often have access to su/reboot commands, but for an off-the-shelf, commercially available device, no: there is no way to programatically shut it down.

Comment: Taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305491/power-off-or-restart-an-android-device-via-code-program

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

In that case is there any listener to detect pop ups or dialog windows so that I can trigger OK button?

Comment: AFAIK You cannot determine if a dialog is shown. You can determine only if you are generating the dialog in your code, but in your case you need to determine if there is a dialog generated by the system. I searched a lot but couldnt find anything too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a dicey one! As an app, you cant do much, but there is one way you can try this. Get a phone which is rooted and grants your application SuperUser permissions. Then you could try to run this piece of code from your APK.

```
Process mProcess = null;
DataOutputStream osStream;

try {
        mProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error","Unable to get SU permissions, quitting");
    }
    osStream = new DataOutputStream(mProcess.getOutputStream());
try {
        osStream.writeBytes("reboot");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Not a tested piece of code, but hopefully should give you some idea!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't really invoke the shutdown programmatically in non-rooted device, there's a way how to disable the confirmation dialog that occurs when you long-press the power button. There's a secret code

`*#*#7594#*#*`
or
`*#7594#`

which changes the power button behaviour - enables direct power off once the code enabled. You need to choose this code via default dialpad. Works on most Android phones.

[Here's the list of some other secret codes.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1sl0ep/list_of_android_secret_codes_tips_and_tricks/)