# How to set time and date for power on/ power off of an Android device

Tags: android

I am developing an app that should power off nad on the device (an Android TV) at specified days of week, at a certain hour. Alarms work on time intervals; how do I set an absolute date and time for a certain action? Is it possible?

Comment: Please look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305491/power-off-or-restart-an-android-device-via-code-program`

Comment: "Alarms work on time intervals" -- have you read the `AlarmManager` documentation? Have you looked at its `set()` method?

Comment: Yes, I read the AlarmManager set() documentation, so what??? No mention of setting a specific date and time for alarm, as far as I can see.