# Reboot android device programmatically

Tags: android, restart, reboot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reboot the phone on a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966486/reboot-the-phone-on-a-button-click)

Is it possible to reboot a device pro grammatically.

I just want to reboot the device on a button click.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?
What error messages did you receive?

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
try {
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot");
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Not working, and my phone is rooted, it not working.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5768966/2128979) worked for me : `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot now"});`