# Restarting a device programmatically

Tags: android, reboot

In my android application, I want to restart my android device on button click.
But its not working.
I have done this so far.

```
ImageButton restartmob = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.restartmob);
    restartmob.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Process proc = null;            
            try {
               //proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
                 proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot now"});
                proc.waitFor();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Could not reboot", ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Also I put the following permission in the manifest file.

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/>
```

When I clicked the image button to restart, I got the following exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/bin/su, -c, reboot now] 
Working Directory: null Environment: null   
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)   
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128)
at com.android.onlinepayment.activity.SystemSubMenuActivity$1.onClick(SystemSubMenuActivity.java:49)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)   
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)  
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory   
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
... 13 more
```

What's wrong with my code? Please help me on this.
For the info, I am testing on android Lollipop (if it matters).
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966486/reboot-the-phone-on-a-button-click

Answer (score 26):

The permission you required is not related to your reboot method, as your method requires a rooted phone (with `su`). To reboot the phone, require the permission as you did, but call [`PowerManager#reboot`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot(java.lang.String)).

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.reboot(null);
```

Comment: I got this exception:  
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10695 nor current process has android.permission.REBOOT.

Comment: It seems that the permission only takes effect if your application is a system application, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature

Comment: This is not working in my case either and getting same exceptiojn as @Suniel gets.

Comment: What if I have a rooted phone, app with root access, and installed as system and it gives the same error as Suniel? (java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user [don't remember] nor current process has android.permission.REBOOT). It's said here that the protectionLevel is signature|privileged: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/8cbdf944528e513293b1e5e738b2c16a525f9520/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#L3785. I'd be the last one, supposedly. Also I'm doing this on Lollipop 5.1, no it shouldn't be the Mashmallow runtime permission request.

Answer (score 17):

On API 24 if your app is the device owner app you can call: `devicePolicyManager.reboot(yourAdminComponent)`

See docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#reboot(android.content.ComponentName))

Comment: what is yourAdminComponent? how to add admin component?

Comment: @AAA the AdminComponent is a ComponentName that is set when you become device owner.  Looks something like "com.mycompany.product/.DeviceOwner", which references a class name.

Answer (score 5):

**Try this...**

```
try {
      Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
      proc.waitFor();
         } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Could not reboot", ex);
      }
```

Add permission reboot

Comment: Is this dependent on android version? Actually I am testing in android 5.0.1

Comment: No need to add permission reboot because you cannot get this permission in your app just use any root permission manager then allow your app by default for root access.

Comment: This is the only working solution for Android 7 with Magisk. Specifying full path by "/system/bin/su" is not working because "/system/bin/su" is not exist by this path.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do a reboot from an ordinary SDK application. Only applications signed with the system firmware signing key can do this.
Copied from this answer,

[Programmatically switching off Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone)

You need the system key to sign your app. See this post for details;

[How to compile Android Application with system permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598662/how-to-compile-android-application-with-system-permissions)

Answer (score 2):

After long struggle i found working solution.

**If your system is used serial port then execute below command,**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot now"});
```

**if use normal port then excure below command**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/xbin/su","-c","reboot now"});
```

difference is only **`/bin`** and **`/xbin`**

> so can code like if first command throw exception then execute second.

Comment: This is not working in my case. it is giving me exception no such directory or file found. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible with root access.
You can use the [LibSuperUser](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser) library or [libsu](https://github.com/topjohnwu/libsu).

```
Shell.SU.run("reboot");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code -

#### First importing package

```
import com.google.android.things.device.DeviceManager;
```

#### Creating function and adding some Exceptions

```
public void StartReboot() throws IllegalStateException, RuntimeException, SecurityException {
```

#### Creating Object

```
      try {
         DeviceManager deviceManager = DeviceManager.getInstance();
```

#### Start Reboot

```
         deviceManager.reboot();
```

#### Catching Exceptions

```
      } catch(IllegalStateException ex) {
        OnError("Underlying system service is not ready.");
      } catch(RuntimeException ex) {
        OnError("Underlying system service encountered an error.");
      } catch(SecurityException ex) {
        OnError("Calling context does not have com.google.android.things.permission.REBOOT permission");
      }
    }
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful for future readers.

Comment: hey @Hoppeduppeanut i will add a short explanation soon as possible

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut please see if it is correct now?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `<permission ... />`.
You need to do `<USES-permission ... />`

The caps are not needed, it was just to emphasise it.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {//   It worked for me on Android 7.0
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("/system/bin/su", "-c", "reboot now"))
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.e(TAG,e.message)
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers didn't consider DevicePolicyManager API. Perhaps you can set your app as Device Admin http://blogs.quovantis.com/android-device-administration-apis/ (user needs to do it specifically from settings) and there is a reboot method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#reboot(android.content.ComponentName).

So I doubt root is needed for sure to do it. I'm writing the app to test it (trying to make remote reboot from computer possible).