# Xamarin- Restart Android Phone Getting System User Access Without Rooting

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

I want to restart android device using code in Xamarin.
I have read many threads and [found one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32984952/3565879) with the following code:

```
try
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
    pm.Reboot(null);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

and I modified my **Manifest** file like below, to get **System level** access:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
<application android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" android:label="Appname" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
```

But I am getting the following exception in the result:

> Java.Lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10523 nor current process has android.permission.REBOOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android.permission.REBOOT` is "Not for use by third-party applications."  Please refer to `REBOOT` of [Manifest.permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).

And currently there is no way to reboot device programmatically without Rooting.