# Should a data application signed with the vendor key be able to run 'su'

Tags: android, root

*Background*: I am developing for a signage device which is to be remotely operated. I need an application that can

- Fetch and install new packages
- Reboot the device (for troubleshooting)

---

I have an unrooted Android device. I also have files which I am told are the platform keys.

I have developed an application which attempts to kick off the `su` process.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Before I signed the application with the platform keys this was throwing an `IOException`, with the message being `Permission Denied`.

I signed the application with these platform keys, and I am still getting the `Permission Denied` exception.

Here are three contradictory statements. Which one of these statements (if any) is correct?

**Statment 1**: This should work. The application, even though is is stored in `/data/app`, should be able to run `su`. Either I have the wrong keys, or there's some other entry I need to add to the manifest to get it to work.

**Statement 2**: This shouldn't work. Even though it is signed with the platform key, the application is in `/data/app`, so it's a data application, not a system application. Data applications cannot run `su` on an unrooted devices. If this application was installed into `/system/app`, then it would be able to run `su`. (And I can't get it into `/system/app` because it's unrooted, so I'm stuck).

**Statment 3**: This will never work. If the device is not rooted, then NOTHING can run `su`, even if it is a signed system app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android shouldn't even have a `su` binary if you didn't flash some sort of root method to the device, such as Magisk or SuperSU.

Even if it does have a `su` binary, I wouldn't expect it to work, for one of two reasons. Assuming that your device comes with a preinstalled `su` binary, who's managing it? If it's unmanaged, it should just deny all requests. If you flash a root method, then it's up to that manager to decide if your app gets access to `su`, regardless of whether you have signature-level permissions or nor (the root manager uses a different signature, after all).

And why would you even need access to `su` as a signature app? You have total access to the device anyway. If you need to run a command, you should have no problems no matter what you run, as long as it's done from your platform-signed package. But since you have full access, the native APIs should let you do everything you need.

As for the IOException returned when you try to execute `su` in a Process, that's just a weird Android quirk. If there's no `su` binary installed, it'll sometimes return `command not found` and other times `permission denied`, depending on the device.

The point I think I'm making is that, unless your app is the root manager, you could be part of the system_server and still have the same access to `su` as everyone else. For which statement I agree with, I think #3, although I don't fully agree with it, because chances are `su` just doesn't exist, or it's a dud binary.

I've explained why #1 shouldn't be true, but #2 is just incorrect. If you look at the [platform manifest](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml), every permission that requires a privileged app can also be granted to signature apps. So even if you did move your app to `/system/priv-app/` (`/system/app/` won't make it privileged), it wouldn't make a difference. Basically, if your app is signed by the platform signature, it doesn't matter where it's installed.

EDIT:

You can easily reboot by just running `reboot` as a command, since you have signature-level access to the system, but it's a little more elegant to use the proper API for this. If you use the API, you get the shutdown animation, but you also let the system shut down gracefully, stopping services and sending the ACTION_REBOOT broadcast to any apps that might be listening for that.

To use the API, first add the following permission to your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE" />
```

Now, where you need to call the reboot action, use the following code:

```
IStatusBarService bar = IStatusBarService.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(Context.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE));
bar.reboot(false); //using true here will reboot to Safe Mode
```

This method is a hidden method, so if you're using Android Studio to edit and compile, it'll error out. You can use reflection, or use [Android Hidden API](https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api) to access it directly.

This is how System UI implements it in the power menu: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/globalactions/GlobalActionsComponent.java

This is the class that implements IStatusBar service: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/statusbar/StatusBarManagerService.java#L969

Comment: Thanks. I would never have guessed that `permission denied` meant `it is not even there`.
In answer to why I need to execute 'su' - I need to remotely restart the device and also remotely update existing packages. Maybe instead of running 'su' I can directly execute 'reboot' or 'pm'?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that. However, you can also use an API to properly shut down the device (let it stop all services, call the shutdown intent, etc). I'll edit my answer with that

Comment: Directly executing the `pm` process works! Thank you for putting me on the right track.

Comment: It appears simpler to reboot the device via the PowerManager service. Is there a technical reason why you would prefer the Status Bar service over the PowerManager service, or is it just the path you've happened to have gone down?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32984952/25216

Comment: @AndrewShepherd just what I found. You can use either. I think they both end up in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Statement 3. This will never work on an unrooted Android device. At least, not on recent Android OS versions (I have no idea if this might work on really old Android devices).

"su" is an application -- there has to be an "su" binary on disk in order to execute it, and Android does not by default provide an "su" binary for security purposes. When you use thirdparty rootkits, they install their own "su" binary to provide a mechanism for the user to elevate themselves to root privileges.

If your app is signed with a special key and granted elevated privileges from startup, why would you need to execute "su" anyway?

Comment: In answer to why I need to execute 'su' - I need to automatically restart the device and also to automatically install new packages. Maybe instead of running 'su' I should just run 'reboot' or 'pm'?

Comment: Yes, that would be what I would try. I've never had a platform key though, so I can't speak from experience.

Comment: Directly executing the `reboot` or `pm` process does indeed work.