# How to send key press action without keyboard in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, keyboard

I want to access the keys on the keyboard without pressing the button, I want to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> without keyboard.

I found this code but it's not working:

```
dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT));
dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT));
dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL));
```

I want to send action of holding all three of these buttons at same time.

Comment: I think you need root and some shell code for doing such a thing.

Comment: This thread here is probably more like what you're looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984849/restart-android-device-programmatically