# Is there anyway to reboot a device programmatically without root?

Tags: android, reboot

I want to reboot my phone using my app,but it requires root .

is there anyway to do it without root ?

My Code :

```
 try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","reboot now"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit : i've heard that we can reboot phone without root using
'devicepolicymanager' .
but i can't understand the official documentation  , if anyone knows it please leave a demo code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984849/restart-android-device-programmatically)

Comment: The answer is in your question: **NO**. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","reboot now"});` You have to run **su**, which is only accessible when you root your device.

Comment: i've tried your given link before and it's not work on unrooted phones.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you need root privileges to achieve this behavior.