# How to restart android device from react native application

Tags: react-native

is there any way we can restart the device from react-native application?. I have done a research whether any npm module available to implement the same logic but unfortunately every npm modules is only to restart the application not the devices.

Anyone please help me to restart the device from react-native application? is there any npm module available for using?? or can we make use of native components??

A help would be really appreciable!! thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can do it will be a big security hole :D

Comment: you simply can't

Comment: so no solution out there to restart the device from app ??. but i saw few android application that does thats why iam wondering :|

Comment: I'm not sure about ios but in android you can do it. you need to add native-module and it's a little bit complicated

Comment: @moloodayat do you have any reference to do this??

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984849/restarting-a-device-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Dont you mean killing the port, and starting metro and running android again? i think its restarting..
like

```
npx kill-port thenumberWhichIsthePort
npx react-native start
npx react-native run-android
```