# how to restart an android phone after x minutes through code

Tags: android, restart, powermanager

I want to restart my phone Suppose after 30 hrs. There is a api  to shutdown phone but is there a api to restart phone?
using `android.os.PowerManager`, function `reboot(String reason)`, I guess we can reboot phone immediately, but how to reboot phone say after 30 hrs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966486/reboot-the-phone-on-a-button-click

Comment: it is not duplicate, because It is not to reboot immediately,I want  the phone would power of now and reboot after x time