# Gaining level 2 permissions on Android

Tags: android, permissions, android-emulator

I need to gain level 2 permissions for an android application, e.g.

**android.permission.DEVICE_POWER** or **android.permission.REBOOT**

Now I know that I need to have the firmware's signing key to be able to do this, but I'd like to be able to try it out on the emulator first. I'm unable to find any mention of a signing key for a system image for emulators.

Do I have to build an image from scratch (i.e. compile from the source) or is there any way I can get my hands on the signing key?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting them in AndroidManifest?
e.g

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
```

Comment: Yes. During installation of the app, the PackageManager revokes the permission.

Answer (score 0):

See [signatureOrSystem permissions on custom ROM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688352/signatureorsystem-permissions-on-custom-rom/20484747#20484747). Basically unless the app is signed by the system platform signature these permissions can not be granted. Andriod 4.4 introduces the ability to put apps in /system/priv-app as an alternative. This later process requires a custom boot loader and/or root access to install.