# How to Prevent Android program from being closed or removed

Tags: android, kernel

for some reasons i want to  to run a program for andorid and prevent it from being deleted or stop / disable it . from what i have read it's not possible to be done without OS modification and yes we can ask the customers to install the custom modified version of the OS on their phones . but i need to know how to modify the kernel or make the program loaded within it .

Any help regarding this will be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to create a so called system application. Some questions where already [asked here about system apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711047/android-how-can-app-run-as-system-app) so you might find your solution already here.

Comment: thanks for quick answer , but if the phone is rooted this can prevent the root from remove the application or stopping it ?

Comment: A root on a phone is god. And god can do anything. He can also change the kernel. Everything can happen if the phone is rooted. So basically prevent the rooting is the only possible solution.

Comment: can you suggest a way to prevent rooting the OS ?

Comment: No, I am not in the security business. Thats your area :) (at least based on your nickname :D)