# Reboot android device onClick event of Button

Tags: android

i want to Reboot my phone i tried

```
        try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Could not reboot", ex);
}
```

and also PowerManager see my coding but device is not rebooting in both the coding kindly give working code

```
          ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final PowerManager power = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            power.reboot("fav");
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You cannot do a reboot from an ordinary SDK application. Only
>   applications signed with the system firmware signing key can do this.

*Copied from this answer, [Programmatically switching off Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone)*

Comment: You need the system key to sign your app. See this post for details; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598662/how-to-compile-android-application-with-system-permissions

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to programatically reboot on a custom device via just placing the application in /system/app instead of /data/app, not signing it with the same key I used to build Android.
It may also work on a rooted device.
If you want it to work on *any* device where your application is installed through normal means, it can't be done as you can't sign it with system keys for every device.