# Android Inter-app relations

Tags: android, user-interface, emulation

While there are questions relevant to mine, none are quite answering them to the extent of what I was looking for.  First off, is it possible to have a downloadable Android app that "runs on top of another app" that is, it emulates a pre-defined user input and doesn't have a traditional "gui."  For example, (hypothetically) if I had an app that plays videos but is set to auto turn off the screen every 10 seconds, I would want an onTouch event every few seconds in order to prevent this.  Nothing complicated, just touches, maybe a few swipes, and the other events that go along with them.

Secondly, if this is not a valid way to create an app "with no interface, just a pre-defined script, is there any other way that I could "inject" on-touch events into an app that isn't open-source?

EDIT:
To be more specific, I'm looking at making a "quick" app helper, a sort of program that when activated, runs a pre-defined set of instructions that emulate user input at very high speed, so, think of an app that performs some activity (like swiping from object A to object B) and back REALLY fast.  I'm also already looking at speed thresholds on different android devices to find a common (maximum) one that would work for all devices.

Comment: Take a look at the [UI/Application Exerciser Monkey](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) to see one way this might be done. You might also want to clarify your question to specify what it is you are really trying to do. Specifics help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [android.app.Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) class. This lets you send a wide variety of events to an application and monitor the results.

To use this class successfully, your app must have the INJECT_EVENTS permission and [must be signed with the system signing key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598662/how-to-compile-android-application-with-system-permissions). This means you need to be working on a rooted device with your own custom firmware. You won't be able to do this with carrier-provided firwmare.

If your solution doesn't need to be an .apk, then you can try using [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html). This only requires that you are able to connect to the device with adb (i.e. USB debugging is enabled for the device).