# how to enable system firmware key

Tags: android

System signature key  should be used in order to sign my application with system privileges, . But, I donot know. So I have questions ;

- How can I sign my application with system firmware key ?
- What are the requirement ?
- What should I do, step by step?

Comment: Possibly relevant; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598662/how-to-compile-android-application-with-system-permissions

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have your own firmware flashed on your phone, you will not be able to get system signature. If it is your own firmware then you can get the private key

at /build/target/product/security

Take the platform.pk8 file and sign your app using steps described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)