# Install application as system application on rooted device

Tags: android, root, rooted-device

How would you programmatically get the application to install itself in `/system/app` so that it is treated as a System application and not a user app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to programmatically install your app in `/system/app` folder. You can however, ask for root permissions and execute any commands requiring root privileges using this guide:

http://muzikant-android.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html

Comment: I would like to use `INJECT_EVENTS` for which I require the app to be a system app. Is it possible to inject events with only root access but this permission being revoked? I guess not. So, isn't there a possibility to execute commands on the terminal via my app to get it to convert my app into a system app?

Comment: you're right. I haven't tried it before but here are some resources that might help you:
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission
- http://androidforums.com/droid-all-things-root/64603-installing-apk-system-app-directory.html
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598662/how-to-compile-android-application-with-system-permissions