# Launch another android application along with passing data

Tags: android

I did search a lot but I couldn't found my answer. If any one can help, much appreciated.

I am building an android application from that can I launch another application along with passing some required data?

**Example.** 
MyApplication launch "AnotherApplication" that needs username and password.
So can I launch that "AnotherApplication"  along with passing these two parameters?

I don't have control on "AnotherApplication" code. So I can not read data from Intent or something in this. And I dont even know how that application is reading these two parameters(Intent/ input's value etc.)

Is it technically possible? If yes please provide me sample snippet as well to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data passing to another application in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513473/data-passing-to-another-application-in-android)

Comment: you can use - intent.putExtra("Key", "Your data here"); in a similar way as for data passing between the Activities.

Comment: Thanks for quick answers but I do not have control on target application which I am going to launch. So I cannot read data from Intent.getExtra..() kind of things.

Comment: If you don't have control on target application, why do you want to pass the data?

Comment: Can you elaborate, what you actually want?

Comment: In order to pass the data between applications.....one should be sender....and the other one should be receiver......so, you must have control on both and be able to putExtra and getExtra too.

Comment: Yes one should be reciever but the code of receiver is not mine. But I wanted to enter into that (Third party) application without providing the parameters which are been already provided in my application. Basically I wanted to replay those parameters. But I am not sure whether its possible technically or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can attach data, either primitive or Serializable or Parceable, into Intent. Please see [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity)

Answer (score 0):

yes this is a complete example

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  
  EditText etFName;
  EditText etLName;
  
  Button btnSubmit;
  
  
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        etFName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFName);
        etLName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLName);
        
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        
    }


  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class); 
    intent.putExtra("fname", etFName.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("lname", etLName.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
  } 
}
```

and here the other activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewActivity extends Activity {
  
  TextView tvView;
  
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);
    
    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);
    
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    
    String fName = intent.getStringExtra("fname");
    String lName = intent.getStringExtra("lname");
    
    tvView.setText("Your name is: " + fName + " " + lName);
  }
}
```