# How to Reboot Android phone programmatically?

Tags: android

I am trying to reboot Android device through a activity. I'm using following code.

```
public void reboot(){
    PowerManager pm=(PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.Power_Service);
    pm.reboot(null)
}
```

And I have given Manifest permission too.

```
android:name="android.permission.REBOOT
```

> Error::java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10098 nor current
>   process has android.permission.REBOOT.

Answer (score 0):

Only applications signed with the system firmware signing key are allowed to do these operations.

More information can be found in the links below

[How to compile Android Application with system permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598662/how-to-compile-android-application-with-system-permissions)

[Programmatically switching off Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone)

Comment: What about https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#reboot(android.content.ComponentName)

DevicePolicyManager API? You can set your app as device admin without root, but device owner (not firmware signer) needs to do it.