# Inject Touch event in android app

Tags: android, sdk, ui-automation, android-instrumentation

I have developed apps for screen mirroring one is for server and other is receiving server's screens.

Now, i am working on adding Touch events in receiver app and send touch event to server app. As both apps are on different devices so i am making connection using DLNA protocol for the communication.

But i am not able to inject touch event from receiver to server app and not able to achieve the functionality. I want to inject touch events without rooting my devices.

Following is the code that i am using:

```
       m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();

       AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO your background code

            m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,x, y,0));
            m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,x, y,0));
        }
    });
```

The above code giving error that is [Request Permission to inject event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYRyH.png)

As inject_event permission is a system permission so i have to make app as system app. For making system app i have to sign app with system certificates. So i followed the link [How to compile Android Application with system permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598662/how-to-compile-android-application-with-system-permissions) And if i am able to generate app as system app then i have to install it as `/system/app`

but when i am searching for adding app as system app then is asking for root device to get `read/write` access from OS. But i don't want to root the device.

Any helps would be appreciated deeply.

Comment: Maybe you need to write your app as an Android accessibility service (that aside, obviously this raises severe security model implications if what you were trying worked without special permissions...)